# Сохранить в файл ответ по команде ls

Tags: linux, bash

Вывести содержимое домашней папки пользователя в файл с именем "list" в текущей папке.

Comment: `ls ~ > list` .

Comment: вот так просто, спасибо. Сделай в виде ответа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перенаправление вывода программы в файл делается оператором `>`. А оператором `>>` можно дозаписывать в конец файла.

Также можно указать отдельно потоки stderr и stdout добавив соответственно 1 и 2 к оператору. Например:

```
ls /proc/*/fd/ 2> /tmp/errors 1> /tmp/out
```

Выдаст

```
/proc/1008/fd/:
0
1
2
3
4
....
```

и

```
ls: невозможно открыть каталог '/proc/100/fd/': Отказано в доступе
ls: невозможно открыть каталог '/proc/101/fd/': Отказано в доступе
ls: невозможно открыть каталог '/proc/103/fd/': Отказано в доступе
ls: невозможно открыть каталог '/proc/1052/fd/': Отказано в доступе
...
```

в отдельные файлы.

Answer (score 1):

Если надо рекурсивно обойти, то можно так:

```
find ~ > list
```

Comment: А лс умеет деревья рисовать?

Comment: @eri Не знаю... XD

Comment: @eri `ls-lR` даже был неким стандартом (форматом) файлов-листингов каталогов и файлов. Были и парсеры, но это, конечно, не формат дерева.

Comment: `tree` умеет деревья рисовать.

Comment: @МАН69К Я знаю. Могу обновить ответ, или свой напишите.